# What is a "noise word" in postgres-speak?

Tags: postgresql

I was reading the postgres documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS). What does the word "noise" mean in this context?

> This command allows retrieval of system status indicators. CURRENT is
> a noise word

Answer (score 2):

A "noise" word is something that isn't required and doesn't add anything to the functionality or change the outcome of the statement or command.

E.g.`outer` is also considered a "noise" word, because there is absolutely no difference between `left join` and `left outer join` - so the `outer` just adds "noise".

Comment: People in the SQL standard committee seem to like noise words and verbose syntax in general :^)